# Remove exception specifications from C++ code with sed

Tags: c++, regex, bash, sed, exception-specification

I want to automatically remove deprecated exception specifications from my c++ code and try to use sed for this task.

Exception specification format is `throw` following with list of exceptions (words) between parenthesis so I wrote this sed:

```
sed -r 's,throw\s*[(].*[)],,g' foo.cpp
```

It works for oneline specifications but does not work for multiline one's.

It seems like dot does not match newlines althougth according to documentation it have to: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

I tried this workaround but it does not work either (actually it does not even work for oneline specifications):

```
sed -r 's,throw\s*[(][\s\S]*[)],,g'
```

How to make it work properly?

**EDITED**:

example of exception spec:

```
void foo() throw (std::runtime_error);  //oneline

void bar() throw (std::runtime_error,
                  std::logic_error);    //multiline
```

Comment: Provide some sample data..

Comment: The `.` would  match newlines, but sed is a line editor so can only see a single line. Look [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51) for ways to match multiple lines. Although tbh i wouldn't use sed to parse c++ code.

Comment: Sed is not mandatory I need any solution that will work properly.

Comment: Please show an example of the throw command format.

Comment: I have added example of oneline and multiline specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many text editors (for example jEdit) support multi-file regex search & replace.

However, there is no syntactic distinction between a throw specification and a throw expression throwing a parenthesized variable. The two are mostly distinguished primarily by not appearing in the same syntactic context. You could also distinguish them by resolving the name. But that won't work to distinguish the throw expression `throw(foo())`, which throws a default-constructed object of type foo, and the throw specification `throw(foo())`, which makes the absurd but technically valid claim that the annotated function may throw an exception of type "function that takes no arguments and returns a foo".

If you want a reliable way of stripping exception specifications, the best way would be to write a [Clang Tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/index.html) check.

Comment: Thx, I 've used my IDE (QtCreator) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There is a clang-tidy check for this already.

I got it to replace the throw specifications from our source with noexcept(false) with this commandline

```
clang-tidy --fix --checks=-*,modernize-use-noexcept foo.cpp -- -I /my/include/path
```

Compiler options such as include paths and defines need to go after the -- . For further documentation see
https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-use-noexcept.html

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.